# How to send extra **Kwargs to event click method of an ipyvuetify button

Tags: python, button, events, ipyvuetify

I am using ipyvuetify to create a dashboard including several buttons.

here the code for one of them:

```
import ipyvuetify as vue
from ipywidgets import Output

out = Output()
mybtn = vue.Btn(color='primary', children=['Run'])

def btn_method(widget, event, data):
    with out:
        print('btn was clicked')
          
mybtn.on_event('click', btn_method)

display(mybtn,out)
```

My problem is that when clicking a button the actions carried out depend on some varaibles. The question is how can I send to the button extra data, i.e. a dictionary of data.

Pseudo code:

```
import ipyvuetify as vue
from ipywidgets import Output
out = Output()
mybtn = vue.Btn(color='primary', children=['Run'])
# t followoing does not work, nor it gives an error:
def btn_method(widget, event, data, **kwargs):
    with out:
        print('btn was clicked')
        print(len(kwargs))
    if myvar==4:
        #do this
        pass
    else:
        #do that
        pass
             
mybtn.on_event('click', btn_method, kwargs={'myvar':4})

display(mybtn,out)
```

Of course the error is: on_event() got an unexpected keyword argument 'kwargs', i.e. you are not supposed to send other vars into the on_event method.

Any idea how to proceed?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply set your dictionary as an additional attribute of the button object and read it inside the callback function.

```py
mybtn = vue.Btn(color='primary', children=['Run'])

def btn_method(widget, event, data):
    with out:
        print('btn was clicked')
        print(widget.kwargs)
    if widget.kwargs['myvar']==4:
        #do this
        pass
    else:
        #do that
        pass
             
mybtn.on_event('click', btn_method)
mybtn.kwargs={'myvar':4}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use `functools.partial` to make a new callback
function on-the-fly, that would have the extra args you want to pass already defined:

```py
import functools

def btn_method(widget, event, data, **kwargs):
    with out:
        print('btn was clicked')
        print(len(kwargs))
    if kwargs.get("myvar")==4:
        #do this
        pass
    else:
        #do that
        pass
             
mybtn.on_event('click', functools.partial(btn_method, myvar=4))
```

(untested code)

Comment: it works, phantastic, now I have to understand why!!!

Comment: functools.partial -->https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZlOy1BY6lY